# Typescript - Class implements an interface without defining fields

Tags: typescript, class-transformer

I would like to create a class that implements an interface without defining the fields. Is there a way to achieve this without a TS error?

```
type Foo = {
  bar: string;
};

class FooClass implements Foo {}
```

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sunset-j515by?file=/src/index.ts)

The reason I would like to do this is because I want to transform my api data into a class to add some utility functions. However, because I define the fields on the class I lose any type safety if the type that the class implements changes (i.e. the property is removed).

Comment: Try `class FooClass implements Partial<Foo> {}`

Comment: It's messy, but by stepping away from the `class` keyword, kind-of achievable: https://tsplay.dev/w8Ev9N

Comment: Using partial doesn't really achieve what I want and will make me have to optionally chain everything

Comment: @spender That's what I was considering but I would be surprised if there was not a way to do what I want with some kind of config. As it's perfectly valid to construct a class without the fields being defined.

Comment: Here is a more concrete example: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sunset-j515by?file=/src/usage.ts

Comment: If `FooClass implements Foo` and you don't define the `bar` property, then what will I get when I write `new FooClass().bar.toUpperCase()`?  A runtime error?  (Then `FooClass implements Foo` is not true)  Or some string? (Then where did the initial string value come from?)  Or, wait, do you *not* use `--strictNullChecks`?  I think I'm confused about what you're trying to achieve here.  Could you clarify, perhaps with usage examples?

Comment: codesandbox.io/s/keen-sunset-j515by?file=/src/usage.ts is a what I'm trying to achieve. My types are generated from a GraphQL request and are the source of truth. I take that response and transform it to a class to add some utility functions. 

The issue arises when I change my request, the type that is generated is not the source of truth because the class is defining the properties aswell as implementing the interface.

if I can define the class without having to set the properties and let typescript infer the properties from the interface, I would be able to maintain the source of truth